Getting ebpf ringbuf stats from userspace
I have an ebpf program which is attached to a kprobe using which I collect information and queue info via ringbuf for userspace to consume. I was looking for a way I can get ebpf ringbuf stats from userspace.
I saw we have bpf_ringbuf_query api which I can use to get needed stats in kernel space. I was thinking of using the same to store the information in a stats map and read from userspace. However I am unable to figure out a way I can trigger this api to be called.
I was thinking to update the map whenever I queue the info in ringbuf by calling the query api , however I couldnt figure out a way to update the map when the queue is consumed from userspace.
Any help is appreciated..

Couldn't you call bpf_ringbuf_query and update the map every time you write to the ring buffer? Then userspace would always have the latest info at time of write.
